# Consume $args while also using parameter set names

Tags: powershell, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

Consider the following toy example script `test.ps1`:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='readfile',Position=0,Mandatory=$True)]
    [string] $FileName,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='arg_pass',Mandatory=$True)]
    [switch] $Ping
)

if ($Ping.isPresent) {
    &$env:ComSpec /c ping $args
} else {
    Get-Content $FileName 
}
```

The desired effect would be that

```
.\test.ps1 FILE.TXT
```

displays the contents of `FILE.TXT` and

```
.\test.ps1 -Ping -n 5 127.0.0.1
```

pings localhost 5 times.

Unfortunately, the latter fails with the error

```
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'n'.
At line:1 char:18
+ .\test.ps1 -Ping -n 5 127.0.0.1
+                  ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [test.ps1], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,test.ps1
```

This is just a minimal example, of course.

In general, I am looking for a way to introduce a `[switch]` parameter to my script that lives inside its own parameter set and when that switch is present, I want to consume all remaining arguments from the commandline and pass them on to another commandline application. What would be the way to do this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` parameter attribute. I would also recommend specifying a default parameter set name in `CmdletBinding`. Example:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="readfile")]
param(
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="readfile",Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
    [String] $FileName,
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="arg_pass",Mandatory=$true)]
    [Switch] $Ping,
  [parameter(ParameterSetName="arg_pass",ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
    $RemainingArgs
)
if ( $Ping ) {
  ping $RemainingArgs
}
else {
  Get-Content $FileName 
}
```

(Aside: I don't see a need for `& $env:ComSpec /c`. You can run commands in PowerShell without spawning a copy of cmd.exe.)

Comment: First of all, +1 and thanks. The `& $env:ComSpec /c` enters because in my *actual* code, I am calling a batch file. Please do correct me if I am wrong, but I think that's the way to do it?

Comment: You don't have to _explicitly_ spawn cmd.exe to run a batch file. You can test this yourself directly at a PowerShell prompt: Type the name of a batch file and press `Enter`, and you will see that PowerShell will run it.

Comment: I remember now what the problem was. Try executing a batch file with a space in its path. Putting it in quotes will only yield a string, but not putting it in quotes does not work for obvious reasons, either.

Comment: If there is whitespace in the command you want to use, you have to use the invocation/call operator (`&`) and quote it;  otherwise PowerShell will interpret it as a string expression. (You still don't need to explicitly run cmd.exe.)